# LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following structure for table `categories`:

[image]

And I'm trying to do a self join on `parentId = id` to get the parent category but I also want the query to include the row without the join.
I tried doing:

```
select *
from `project.dataset.categories` c
left join `project.dataset.categories` p1 on p1.id = c.parentId or p1.id = c.id
```

But this throws

> LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

For reasons I can't understand.

So basically I'm expecting something like this in the end:

[image]

Sadly using union is **not** an option because this is just a simplification of a much more complex query.

Any help appritiated.

Comment: You need a better explanation of what you want.  `UNION ALL` clearly solves the problem that you have stated.  You should use that solution.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes I know but in reality I do this join 15 times and would eventually require each of the "original" rows as well so union wouldn't work because I'd need to adress the previous dataset which would end up with a lot of repeated code that i'd like to avoid.

Comment: You can use a CTE so the code only needs to be written once.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ya I thought about it but I read that using a CTE really runs the query twice it'll take the query time much longer as the original query is more complex.

Comment: I believe BigQuery enforces an explicit equality condition on left joins to prevent accidental fanouts (which can incur latge storage costs if you were writing to table).  Your query has conditional join logic (`or`), which seems to be the issue here.  Another solution not outlined here is to do 2 self-joins (1 on parentID and 1 on id), then use `coalesce` or `case` statments to select which fields you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
select cc.*
from `project.dataset.categories` c cross join
     unnest(array[id, parent_id]) c_id left join
     categories cc
     on cc.id = c_id
-- where c.id = 2106  -- you seem to want this condition as well
```

This creates an array with the two columns you want to join -- and then unnests them into two separate rows for the `join`.

Or just use `or` and `exists`:

```
select c.*
from `project.dataset.categories` c
where c.id = 2106 or
      exists (select 1
              from `project.dataset.categories` c2
              where c2.id = 2016 and c2.parentid = c.id
             );
```

Comment: The first part seems to duplicate the rows as expected, could you perhaps explain a bit what it does?